# Correct way to use decltype as trailing return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, decltype, perfect-forwarding

I very often see example of this form:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto add(T&& t, U&& u) -> decltype(std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u))
{
    return std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u);
}
```

but I dare to say that this is better more correct way:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto add(T&& t, U&& u) -> decltype(t + u)//no forwarding here
{
    return std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u);
}
```

Why? First and foremost, decltype in this example has only to deduce return type so (t + u) is the return type not (std::forward(t) + std::forward(u)), second code generated by two ver is identicall, and third decltype(u + t) is more direct and expresses exactly what the intentions of a programmer are without bringing out "guts" of implementation.

What is your opinion on this subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I cannot think of a sensible use case where there will be a difference, but I guess that you could find some case where the operation has different implementations for rvalue-references and rvalues, and the language rules do not dictate that the return type of the different overloads has to be the same (even if common sense would dictate it).

So, in the general case, there will be no difference, and in the case where there are differences, well, those cases need extra care and attention for much worse problems than the template itself...

```
// sick corner case:
struct type {};
int operator+( type&& lhs, type&& rhs );
double operator+( type const & lhs, type const & rhs );
```

I can think on situations where you would like to offer different overloads for rvalue-references (consider some implementation of a list that offers `operator+` as concatenation, then an overload with rvalue references could avoid the cost of copying by just mangling with the pointers and leaving the argument lists empty), but it would be utterly confusing if the type of the result would depend on the l/rvalue-ness of the arguments.

Comment: the more I use the decltype the more I'm convinced that it should operates on types not on objects. Because it is more natural to think of what is the result of adding two types instead of two objects of these types.

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: I don't quite agree with that, there is a clear advantage in using objects instead of types: the compiler will perform any required conversion on the arguments: `template <typename T, typename U> auto sum( T lhs, U rhs ) -> decltype( lhs+rhs ) { return lhs+rhs; }` will convert to the greater of `T` and `U` for arithmetic types. `template <typename T> auto foo( T x ) -> decltype( foo_(x) ) { return foo_(x); }` will perform any implicit conversion that might be required from the actual `T` to the *best* overload of `foo_` available...

Comment: I guess that you could also think that `decltype( foo( int ) )` could be used in the grammar, but that would create the first case of `id( type )` that is not a perfect match (in all other uses, there can be no conversion from `int`) and would probably lead to confusion. What `foo` is that one you are talking about? I only have `foo(doble)` and `foo(string)`!

Answer (score 3):

The first version is more correct because it matches exactly what the function body is going to return. As already pointed out, there is simply no guarantee that

```
decltype(std::forward<T>(t) + std::forward<U>(u))
```

will be the same type as

```
decltype(t + u)
```

Arguably, this is quite a corner case, but the "correct" way is to use std::forward.

Answer (score 2):

Within `decltype(t + u)`, the variables `t` and `u` are already no rvalue references anymore, they'd get treated as simple lvalue references, hence you need the aditional `std::forward`.
(Atleast, that's how I understand it. Could be wrong though.)

Comment: but this is only to deduce retur type, nothing else, you don't do anything with those variables in decltype.

Comment: @There: That might still be important, as there might be a special overload of the `operator+` for rvalue references.